# Cannot read property 'getSubjectifs' of undefined

Tags: angular

i'm new to angular 4, i have a task where i should get a list of names from Json files, Here is my AppService where i'm getting the Json file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()

export class AppServices {


private _url: string = "assets/data/queryoptions.json";

constructor(private http: Http) {

}

getSubjectifs() {
    return this.http.get(this._url)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}

}
```

here is my component

```
ngOnInit(): void {


    this.form = this._fb.group({
        items: new FormArray([])
    });
    this.refrech();

}
refrech(): void {
    this.appservice.getSubjectifs().subscribe(ressubjectifsdata => this.subjectifs = ressubjectifsdata);
}



So any idea why i'm getting Cannot read property 'getSubjectifs' of undefined ?
```

Comment: Did you inject `appservice` in your constructor?

Comment: Also if you inject it, checkout the naming, it might be this.appService

Comment: Yeah the problem was in Constructor , i just need to add 
private appservice : AppServices to my constructor , and 
also i need to add ".subjectifs" to make this working , 
thnks all 
 this.appservice.getSubjectifs().subscribe(ressubjectifsdata => this.subjectifs = ressubjectifsdata.subjectifs);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to inject the service in your component :

```
constructor(private appservice: AppServices ) {

}       
refrech(): void {
     this.appservice.getSubjectifs().subscribe(ressubjectifsdata => this.subjectifs = ressubjectifsdata);
}
```